# A problem on Newton-Raphson method

Tags: numerical-methods, transcendental-equations

> The function $f(x)=0$ has a simple root in the interval $(1,2)$. The function $f(x)$ is such that $|f(x)|>3$ and $|f''(x)|\leq 4$ for all $x\in (1,2)$. Assuming that the Newton-Raphson method converges for all initial approximations in $(1,2)$, find the maximum number of iterations required to obtain the root correct upto 6 decimal places after rounding.

I know that Newton-Raphson method converges if $|f(x)f''(x)|<|f'(x)|^2$. I don't how to use it here and how to get the maximum number of iterations required. Please help.

Comment: Very rough sketch: First you know that the sequence converges so after a few itterations we should have $|f(x)|\ll 1$. Use Taylor expansion to get [something like] $x_{n+1}-x_{*} \simeq \frac{1}{2}\frac{f'(x_n)f''(x_n)}{f'(x_{n})^2 - f''(x_n)f(x_n)}(x_{n+1}-x_*)^2 \approx \frac{1}{2}\frac{f''(x_n)}{f'(x_{n})}(x_{n}-x_*)^2$ valid when $f(x)$ is small. You can use the constraints in the problem to show that there is a $C<1$ such that $|x_{n+1}-x_*| \leq C |x_{n}-x_*|^2$ which would allow you to estimate the number of itterations needed.

Comment: You mean $|f'(x)|>3$ on that interval, so $C<\frac23$? Then the number of iterations has to satisfy $(\frac23)^{2^n}<\frac23\cdot\frac12\cdot 10^{-6}$.